How to configure Visual Studio Code to use Visual Studio Professional 2019 tools without .NET SDK in PATH?
I have Visual Studio Professional 2019 installed:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe

When I open my project folder from the command line with code ., I get the following output in Visual Studio Code:
Starting Spawn .NET server...
Starting opening a solution...
Starting processing the solution file "path\to\file.sln" in Dev Kit server...
Failed to find dotnet from path with "where.exe dotnet".
Cannot find .NET SDK installation from PATH environment. C# DevKit extension would not work without a proper installation of the .NET SDK accessible through PATH environment. Rebooting might be necessary in some cases. Check the PATH environment logged in the C# DevKit logging window. In some cases, it could be affected how VS code was started.
PATH=C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
Using local .NET runtime at "c:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime\.dotnet\8.0.8~x64~aspnetcore\dotnet.exe"
.NET server started and IPC established in 1003ms
Completed Spawn .NET server (1858ms)
Completed processing the solution file "path\to\file.sln" in Dev Kit server (2442ms)
Starting restoring NuGet packages...
Selected configuration: <Default>, active configuration: Debug|Any CPU
Completed opening a solution (2471ms)
Starting command: "dotnet.exe" restore path\to\file.sln --interactive...
Failed to monitor project loading status.
Starting Query for all projects...
Failed at 'Query for all projects' (38ms) with error: Error: Exception while talking to proxy: Error: One or more errors occurred. (No installed .NET SDK was found on the computer. If it is installed, make sure it can be found through the PATH environment variable.)

I want to know how I can diagnose and resolve the issue, preferably using the JSON files, primarily the .vscode/settings.json file. I don't want to use dotnet.exe. I think I need to find out the ".NET SDK" that comes with Visual Studio Professional 2019.

This question is similar to: Visual Studio Code for .NET Framework. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@shingo thanks for the informative link. I read through the question and answers on that page. It seems like the question in not about Visual Studio, but a non-Microsoft implementation of .NET Framework? Also the answers are around modifying the .csproj file which I rather not to touch for now.

@shingo I was on the impression that I can solve the problem through the settings.json file.

Looks like VS Code didn't detect the .NET correctly. Can you confirm that C:\Program Files\dotnet folder exists? Try to install it manually if it didn't exist. Please check the system environment variables(Path) as well, make sure that C:\Program Files\dotnet path has been set correctly. If all these things have been checked, please try to reboot your machine and run code . again.

I installed .NET SDK from VS Installer > Modify > Individual components. It seems that for VS 2019, related .NET SDK(come with VS 2019, note that some are out of support) will be installed to C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App directory.

@Tianyuthanks for the comment but please consider that I can't use dotnet.exe and the whole .NET Core. I want to use Visual Studio Professional 2019, .NET Framework and its SDK, if there is one.

The question is about Visual Studio Code, and how to run/debug a .Net Framework project in it. The main step is to modify the launch.json and tasks.json files to use the specified MSBuild instead of the C# dev kit to build the project.

For Build, it seems easy. No need to edit project file, just firstly add path(system environment variables) for MSBuild.exe and .NET Framework.
As you have VS Professional 2019 installed, the directory for MSBuild.exe should be C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin. For .NET Framework, firstly check this directory => C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework, if the .NET Framework that your project targets doesn’t exist, try to download and install it separately from here.
After adding Path, open/restart VS Code > File > Open Folder and open your project folder. Press Ctrl + ~ to open Terminal window in VS Code, run msbuild, the project should be built.


For running and debugging, the launch.json and the tasks.json files are needed. I tested the method that shared by Mario Figueiredo here, I can confirm that it works correctly.

I knew that you don't want to use C# dev kit extension, but I'm not sure if you consider using C# extension in VS Code. As C# extension provides some features for developing and debugging C# in VS Code, it includes OmniSharp which makes running and debugging .NET Framework projects in VS Code possible, though limited.
I think, maybe you want to call to use VS debugger(in VS Code) instead of VS Code or extension related debugger, right? But I don't think it's possible or maybe it's complex or hard to make it work. I'm just curious, if so, why not directly use VS 2019 to debug :) Anyway, I think use C# extension and OmniSharp to run and debug the project is necessary(I don't find a way to directly call/use MSBuild to debug the project without using C# extension and OmniSharp).
If you consider only using C# extension to run and debug .NET Framework projects in VS Code, I think I can share some notes/tips.

Mario Figueiredo's solution includes Build and Debug.

Due to the limitation, editing the project file is needed, but you don't need to modify many properties. You can focus on following properties:
(i) <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
(ii) <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
(iii) <DebugType>portable</DebugType>

About the launch.json file, focus on following:
(i) "type":"clr"

About the tasks.json file, focus on following:
(i) "command":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"
(ii) "type":"shell"

You might need to uncheck the Omnisharp: Use Modern Net option.



